# Dynamic, Randomized Protocols to Deter Attackers

Tags: attacks, protocols, defense

Imagine a protocol that changed periodically.
What if the order of these fields were changed a lot?
One point in time the protocol might be

```
{ Payload, Checksum, Length, Flags, ID }
```

The next point in time it becomes

```
{ Flags, Checksum, Payload, ID, Flags }
```

After a set period the protocol changes again.

As an attacker, the goal is to know what it is about a target to exploit it or find holes. If it were to change periodically it could be harder for an attacker to know how to exploit a weakness. Also the underlying code, fields, field length, encoding/modulation scheme, and other stuff could be changed.
Of course the client/server would need to be in sync with these changes. This sounds like security through obscurity, but it could delay the attacker.  Has the been done before? If not, does it sound like it could be useful?

Comment: Useful to do what? Often the content of the field is enough to determine what the data is. All you are proposing is to make it harder to determine the key name. With a little regex, one could determine which field is which.

Comment: Useful in delaying the attacker in being able to determine and perform a successful attack. Assuming all the fields were encrypted. Maybe there was a certain field the attacker was interested in. Attackers in general want to know how the protocol is designed and its specifications. If it is constantly changing, it might be harder for them to understand it enough to exploit it.

Comment: This sort of thing has been done, but they tend to fail and people return to a clear, clean, and knowable protocol.

Comment: Thanks. Would you happen to know any links to more information about this or tool names?

Comment: I've been searching my memory since I made my comment - I cannot recall  the name of a specific protocol. You can extrapolate from proprietary protocols that have tried to keep their spec a secret and how they all tend to adopt public and open standards (I'm looking at you, Netware\IBM\Windows).

Answer (score 1):

> If it were to change periodically it could be harder for an attacker to know how to exploit a weakness. ... the underlying code ... **Of course the client/server would need to be in sync with these changes.**

As you found out yourself - client and server would need to be in sync. This means that there would need to be some state held on both sides or the server must be able to extract the state from the clients messages and but the client should not be able to invent its own state. If you closer look at these requirements you already have the typical forms of either symmetric encryption (i.e. state relates to encryption key) or authentication (state similar to session cookie). Both are these are established and simple techniques so why invent a new one which is more complex and does not really offer better protection:

- With a session cookie like state you first check if the client is authenticated before you interpret the rest of the data. No need to change the format for the rest because it gets ignored anyway if authentication fails.
- With encryption data must be first decrypted. No need to change the format because the payload gets ignored if the decryption fails.

At the ends the security depends only on how hard the common state can be guessed by the attacker. It does not matter if this state is an encryption key, a session cookie or some algorithm which describes format changes. Only that the latter is more complex to implement than the other two solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you are looking at TCP itself, but the parser would have to determine the layout in some fashion in an out of band situation. You could build it into the communication stack and rotate based on a pre shared secret, but eventually it would be discovered. Probably a window of 6 months?

Also any regularity of your data makes it easier to figure where the byte boundaries are and figure out the scheme.